# Contact form bootstrap php

Tags: php

I'm going to be upfront here. I don't really know PHP, but I want to use it to make a simple email form for my website that I'm building. I have put together what I thought would work, but I still get errors when I click submit.

Can anyone just tell me what I'm doing wrong to get it to work?

Here's the code (sorry if I over posted the code, I don't have the slightest clue where the problem is):

Contact.html:

```
  <h1 class="cover-heading">Contact Me</h1>
        <div class="form-area">
          <form role="form" method="post" action="Contact.php">
            <br style="clear:both">

            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name"
                required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"
                required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number"
                required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject"
                required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"
                maxlength="1337" rows="7"></textarea>
              <span class="help-block"><p id="characterLeft" class="help-block ">You have reached the limit</p></span>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary ">Submit Form</button>

          </form>
        </div>
```

Contact.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "christopherbare@outlook.com";
$email_subject = "ChristopherBare.com Contact form";

function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}


// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['subject']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['mobile']) ||
    !isset($_POST['message'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
}



$name = $_POST['name']; // required
$email = $_POST['email']; // required
$mobile = $_POST['mobile']; // not required
$subject = $_POST['subject']; //required
$message = $_POST['message']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($message) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The message you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}



$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
$email_message .= "Mobile: ".clean_string($mobile)."\n";
$email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($message)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>





<?php

}
?>
```

Here is the error:

```
"; echo $error."

"; echo "Please go back and fix these errors.

"; die(); } // validation expected data exists if(!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['subject']) || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['mobile']) || !isset($_POST['message'])) { died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.'); } $name = $_POST['name']; // required $email = $_POST['email']; // required $mobile = $_POST['mobile']; // not required $subject = $_POST['subject']; //required $message = $_POST['message']; // required $error_message = ""; $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/'; if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) { $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.
'; } $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/"; if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) { $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.
'; } if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) { $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.
'; } if(strlen($message) < 2) { $error_message .= 'The message you entered does not appear to be valid.
'; } if(strlen($error_message) > 0) { died($error_message); } $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n"; function clean_string($string) { $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href"); return str_replace($bad,"",$string); } $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n"; $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n"; $email_message .= "Mobile: ".clean_string($mobile)."\n"; $email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($subject)."\n"; $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($message)."\n"; // create email headers $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n". 'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); ?>
```

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: When I click the submit button, it just returns the validation error that there is nothing in the form.

Comment: which validation?

Comment: Run the code, post the snapshot of error!

Comment: I posted an edit with the error above.

Comment: that is not error, have you installing php server in your system?

Comment: I have not. As I mentioned above, I don't know much about php. I will do that

Comment: PHP script wont run if you doesn't have php installed on your system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your error, look like you doesn't have PHP installed in your system.

You can download PHP here : http://php.net/downloads.php

If you are using Windows OS, I suggest you install xampp for easy use. You can download xampp here : https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: I have installed it through apt and restarted my apache2.service stuff. Still isn't working. I also tried to put it on my domain ftp and that returned a 500 internal server error. I feel like I'm just missing something entirely

Comment: have you try to open localhost on yout browser to check if your php installed succesfully?

Comment: All I get is the apache2 default page. I am currently just editing my site in Atom and then just viewing the files in the browser. I don't know how to check if php is installed or not

Comment: what OS u using? you must copy your file to htdocs or http folder, please read the manual for installing your PHP

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Comment: you should copy your files to /var/www/ ,  please read the php manual carefully

Comment: Okay, I did that. I ran script again and it formatted it to this: `We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. These errors appear below.

The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.
The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.
The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.


Please go back and fix these errors.
` I feel I am getting closer

Comment: Your PHP is ok now. Please make sure you complete all your column before pressing the submit button. And you must install mail server in your system. You are really need to read the manual how it is done. This is too broad now

Comment: I think I have it working now. Yeah, I'm going to go read the manual on this stuff. It works now that I have fixed my php script a bit. Thank you!